# Having issues with a GraphQL schema in Apollo

Tags: javascript, express, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'm building an Express server with Apollo 2. I have the following schema:

```js
const typeDefs = gql `{     
    type Movie {
      id: ID!
      title: String
      year: String
      rating: String      
    }

    type Query {
      movies: [Movie]
    }
  }`;
```

When I run the app, I am getting this error:

`GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found !`

Here's the list of packages I am using (irrelevent packages removed):

`"apollo-server-express": "^2.8.2",
 "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
 "express": "^4.17.1",
 "graphql": "^14.4.2",
 "graphql-tools": "^4.0.5",`

I've done this with version 1 and had no issue. Am I missing a package? Is there a typo or change in the syntax that I missed? I've been looking at this for a couple of hours and cannot figure what the problem is.

Thanks,
James

Comment: I think what you did was pushed it down the tree and left a gap at the top.  The server got confused because type should be before the first bracket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to wrap your document with a pair of curly brackets. It should just be

```
const typeDefs = gql`     
  type Movie {
    id: ID!
    title: String
    year: String
    rating: String      
  }

  type Query {
    movies: [Movie]
  }
`
```

When using SDL, curly brackets are only used when specifying a list of fields or the values of an enum.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!